# How 'experimental' is \TrimSpaces today?

Tags: expl3, xparse, latex-base

The documentation of `xparse` dated 2022-06-22 describes the argument processor `TrimSpaces` which can be used to remove leading and trailing spaces with example

```
\NewDocumentCommand \foo
  { > { \TrimSpaces } m }
  { \showtokens {#1} }
```

But, there is a warning: **This function is experimental**

However, `\TrimSpaces` is now part of the current LaTeX kernel. I used to expect everything inside the kernel as to be not *experimental* but *stable*. So, my guess is that the warning is outdated (?).

Since I really would like to use `\TrimSpaces` for my documents and also for packages, I want to get sure and ask hereby, if anything speaks against using `\TrimSpaces` for *official stuff*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for the 'stable' parts of `xparse` has moved to `usrguide3`: we are intending to tidy up a bit here. Like other parts of `xparse` which were moved to `ltcmd`, `\TrimSpaces` is 'fully stable' today.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply. Your answer is what I hoped for :-)

Comment: Also thank you for pointing me to `usrguide3`. From old habit I still looked into `xparse` for feature documentation, but I will drop this in future for `usrguide3`.